# How to make Picasa copy also .RAW /.NEF files but not show them

Tags: windows-7, photos, picasa, removable

I'm using Picasa to import, manage, upload and back-up pictures. However, I do not want to see duplicates when browsing them, but I would like to copy the raw files from the cameras SD cards, looks like picasa does not copy all files from the card, but only the pictures it shows.

I could use "normal" windows copy, but this does not create separate folders for each day (and does not make picasa index the photo folders until I start it again).

So, is there an easy way for to either:

1. make picasa piggyback the `.NEF` files along with the jpg:s; or
2. add a new default action (in win 7) that copies both `.NEF` and `.JPG` from the card to a default folder, creating a new subfolder for each day taken and on completion open Picasa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been answered in the [Photography section of StackExchange](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1975/best-way-to-import-and-save-when-shooting-in-both-raw-and-jpeg).

Comment: It indeed seems that it has been answered there. However, none of the answers actually answers my question. In any case, it looks like Adobe lightroom is the way to go.